# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'

Tags: xcode, swift

I am implementing a search interface for my application, so basically I will pass the search keyword from one ViewController to another ViewController.

I have done this type of parameter passing several times but something seems strange this time. The destination ViewController is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Now the code looks something like this.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue?.identifier == "home_to_search") {

       var searchKeyword = txtSearchBarHome.text
       var svc = segue?.destinationViewController as! SearchViewController;
       svc.toPassSearchKeyword = searchKeyword;

       //let nav = segue?.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
       //let svc = nav.topViewController as! SearchViewController
       //svc.toPassSearchKeyword = searchKeyword;
    }
}
```

I have already explored these questions
[DestinationViewController Segue and UINavigationController swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573635/destinationviewcontroller-segue-and-uinavigationcontroller-swift), [How do I segue values when my ViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641325/how-do-i-segue-values-when-my-viewcontroller-is-embedded-in-an-uinavigationcontr) with no luck.

What makes me wonder is that I already have ViewControllers embedded in Navigation Controllers that I can pass parameters by segueing. However, in this case it throws a **Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'** error. If I try the commented code above it does not throw an error there, but at the **AppDelegate** class.

Comment: I sometimes run into this when I haven't set my custom class in the interface builder on my UIViewController or UINavigationController. Check the 3rd tab when you select your item in interface builder and check you've set it correctly.

Comment: First, thank you. But I checked from the story board and it seems to point out the correct class.

Comment: It sounds like if you're pushing to a navigationController you may need to get the child viewcontroller (your searchviewcontroller) to pass it a value. Does this make sense? EDIT: Sorry I saw your commented out code. That's exactly what I would have done. I'll investigate to see if i can find the issue. What error does it throw at appdelegate?

Comment: I found the issue. There was a missing mapping in the UI, which worked fine with the commented code. There is still another issue but it seems that    this problem is now solved. Please convert it as answer, so I can mark it as solved. Thanks a lot for pointing out to the right direction.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Answering my own question. In this case we need to access the child view by doing something like this:

```
let nav = segue?.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
let svc = nav.topViewController as! SearchViewController
svc.toPassSearchKeyword = searchKeyword;
```

Comment: Ran into same issue but since I have multiple segues I had to perform a check on the type of class first. segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController)

Comment: Thank you! This is currently an issue in "App Development with Swift" by Apple, on page 551 when they ask you to downcast the segue.destination as! AddEditEmojiTableViewController, forgetting that there is a navigation controller sat in between the two. I'm noticing the quality of this book get worse as I'm going through it, it started super solid, now some of it is getting questionable toward the end - intentionally or not.

Comment: This helped me as well. Most guides forget about this part!

Comment: @Othyn I am looking at the same tutorial, and am now in this stackoverflow question because of the same thing :) you can look at it in a good way tho, its teaching us how to solve these kinds of errors. its not trivial specially for a newbie like me, but it feels good to solve it, simple as it may be :P

Answer (score 5):

Based on Semih's answer, you can also do this to pass a variable to next segue if you don't want to use an identifier:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, 
        let vc = nav.topViewController as? TestViewController {
        vc.username = "Test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note for those looking into this issue it has been renamed to Destination

```
let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let svc = nav.topViewController as! SearchViewController
svc.toPassSearchKeyword = searchKeyword;
```